# sql information arranged to mail

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to send an email through c# with information brought of sql, I solved the sending email issue, but I need to make a data arrangement, the thing is that I need to run the check every 5 minutes and calculate the percentage of the weight and check if there are more than 1 register per production order to recieve a mail when a production Order accomplishes one of three cases:

```
case 1: when a register is more than 50kg
case 2: when two or more registers from the same production order are equal or more than 50kg
case 3: when one or more registers of the production order are equal or more than 4% of the total amount of the procution order.
```

The information brought by query is:

Production Order
User
Time Registered
weight Registered
Total Weight of the Order

The output should be like:

```
-User register
-Time
-Weight (any of the cases)
-Percentage of the weight
-Production Order
```

Can anyone give me some tips? Thank you

Comment: I think you need to show the schema and point out the fields which are relevant to the requirements.

Comment: Of course, these are the variables:
Production Order Brought by query
User                         Brought by query
Time Registered Brought by query
Weight Regitered Brought by query
Total Weight of the order    Brought by query
Percentage of the weight  Calculated
The Percentage I can calculate it

Comment: what are the data types of the fields? Are they all in the same table? If not, what are the relationships between the tables? All that can affect how SQL is written to filter them. That's what I meant when I said show the schema (i.e. the entity-relations). Don't forget to assume we know _nothing_ about your system :-)